# Find second page with post method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests-html

I want to download a m3u list with a python program but I can't find the results page with the post method if someone can help me solve the problem I would be grateful

URL= "https://playtvnow.com/shop1/order/trial-products/1"

```css
from __future__ import print_function
import requests , json, re,random,string,time,warnings
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
warnings.simplefilter('ignore',InsecureRequestWarning)
post_url='https://playtvnow.com/shop1/modules/addons/LagomOrderForm/api/index.php/cart/registration-type/update'
post_url2='https://playtvnow.com/shop1/modules/addons/LagomOrderForm/api/index.php/cart/billing-details/update'

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
def get_clipmails():     
    Headers_={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0',
              'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
              'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
              'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              'Origin': 'https://playtvnow.com/',
              'Connection': 'keep-alive',
              'Referer': 'https://playtvnow.com/shop1/order/trial-products/1',
              'Accept-Encoding':'gzip'}#, deflate, br'}
    params='details[firstname]='+NAME_TARGET+'&details[lastname]='+LAST_TARGET+'&details[email]='+EMAIL_TARGET+'&details[callingCode]=1&details[phonenumber]='+PHON_TARGET+'&details[companyname]=&details[tax_id]=&details[address1]='+ADRS_TARGET+'&details[address2]='+ADRS_TARGET+'&details[city]='+CITY_TARGET+'&details[state]='+STATE_TARGET+'&details[country]=US&details[password]='+RND_PASS+'&details[password2]='+RND_PASS+'&details[postcode]='+ZIP_TARGET+'&paymentMethod=mailin&details[marketingoptin]=1&details[country-calling-code-phonenumber]=1&acceptTos=&currency=1&'
    post_data2=requests.post(post_url2,headers=Headers_,data=params).text 
    print("POST DATA2:",post_data2)
    post_data=requests.post(post_url,headers=Headers_,data=params).text 
    print("POST DATA:",post_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to the problem is completely missing the fact that the page gets rendered via Javascript. What you get through the request response, is the bare-bone HTML returned by the client, but the Javascript payload doesn't get rendered, and that's why you can't see the content you're looking for.

If you want a purely python solution to this problem, look at Selenium https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/ , which is a framework that 'simulates' a real user in a browser, where the browser takes care of rendering elements.

However, Selenium can get tricky, and since it tends to work with Chromium based browser, it tends to require that you maintain your code and keep up with version updates to make sure to keep up with constant Chrome version update.

I tend to prefer Javascript based solutions like Puppeteer https://pptr.dev/ that don't require so much upkeep.